# exc_bad_instruction (code=exc_i386_invop subcode=0x0)

Tags: ios, swift

So here is the problem I run this function and get this error

exc_bad_instruction (code=exc_i386_invop subcode=0x0)
so I try adding self to it but i still get a error
don't mark this as a duplicate because it is different from other questions

```
func hp()
{    
if haspused == false
{


   pausemen.alpha = 1
   pausemen.alpha = 1
   pausebtnho.alpha = 1




    haspused = true
}
else
{
    UIView.animateWithDuration(2, animations:
        {

            self.pausebtn1.alpha = 0
            self.pausemen.alpha = 0
            self.pausebtnho.alpha = 0
    })

    haspused = false
}
}
```

I tried updating to Swift 2 but that did not work
also haspaused is = false 
in the console there was this message

```
 fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
 (lldb)
```

here are the outlets

```
 @IBOutlet weak var pausebtnho: UIButton!
 @IBOutlet weak var pausebtn1: UIButton!
 @IBOutlet weak var pausemen: UILabel!
```

Comment: Please show your variable declarations. You probably haven't initialized your variables pauseXXX. How do you initialize them?

Comment: there IBOoutlets connected to the main storryboard

Comment: Put `print(pausebtnho, pausebtn1, pausemen)` at the top of your `hp()` method and tell us what you get.

Comment: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)

Comment: It is indicating any of the 3 outlets: `pausebtnho`, `pausebtn1`, `pausemen`, is being nil. Check all `@IBOutlet` connections, and if you are not sure, then remove all connections and re-connect them all again.

Comment: there are all connected the the main story board

Comment: in the view did load i have this and it works @OOPer

Comment: pausemen.alpha = 0
pausebtn1.alpha = 0
pausebtnho.alpha = 0

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Then, the properties get nil with other reasons. Can you create a minimized project and show all relevant code?

Comment: my xcode does not work but i can say this the error only happen when i call hp() form applicationDidResignActive methord but i still need an answer